# Disappearing session cookie - django

Tags: django, session, cookies

I have a weird problem in one of my sites. The site uses Django, but I have no idea if this is a Django issue, or browser issue or something else.

Normally, when a user visits my site a browser-session cookie is set. Then, when the user decides to log in he may set the 'remember me' option which makes the cookie change into a fixed expiration cookie (1 week). I think it's a typical behaviour.

The problem is the session cookie sometimes disappears completely, or - what's even more strange - it's replaced by the older browser-session cookie.

I added a middleware in my app, to monitor all the requests and responses and log them into a file. This way I can give the following example:

1. user visits my site at 17:29:13 - my app sends back a cookie:
   Set-Cookie: sessionid=o1idvjhnf2dgx0c1df7p7pyth1ya1byc; Path=/
2. then he logs in at 17:30:36 - again a new cookie is sent:
   Set-Cookie: sessionid=bjjsxcqceghlx7521vikq3kob1d1fidy; expires=Wed, 18-Jun-2014 17:30:36 GMT; Max-Age=604800; Path=/
3. he actively spends some time on my website, and then, suddenly a request comes at 17:51:13 having sessionid cookie set to o1idvjhnf2dgx0c1df7p7pyth1ya1byc. All the other cookies (csrftoken, __utmXXX) remain unchanged. Only sessionid reverted back to the old value, which IMO should've been forgotten for a long time. 
   And from the user's POV he's been logged out.

As far as I can tell this problem occurs in various browsers - this one, above, was in Firefox, but I have a IE11 user complaining about this problem (losing session randomly).

As said above - the session cookie not always reverts back to browser-session cookie - sometimes it just disappears, while again all the remaining cookies (csrftoken etc) are left intact.

I can't reproduce this problem on my computer, so I ask here if you ever experienced any problem like this and can suggest any explanation.

I'm using Django 1.5, with mostly standard session settings except:
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True